# assertEqual or assertNotEqual depending on condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm using this function in my unitests:

```
def assertConditionally(a, b, condition):
    if condition:
        self.assertEqual(a, b)
    else:
        self.assertNotEqual(a, b)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.assertEqual(a == b, condition)
```